# MVC Attribute Routing Controller issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a URL `https://localhost/api/Books/{value}` using attribute routing , but whenever I pass `{value}` as `null` or empty string WEB API is not able to route it to the desired controller? How to go about this issue and resolve it.Error message details is : No action was found on the controller 'Books' that matches the request."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've registered the default route, a request to...

```
http://localhost/api/books/34
```

will be handled by the followung controller/action without even using attribute routing...

```
public BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id){...}
}
```

however, if you need attribute routing you decorate your action method with the following attribute...

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/books/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id){...}
```

Comment: but for some reason I need attribute routing over here , so how to go about it now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a URI parameter optional by adding a question mark to the route parameter. If a route parameter is optional, you must define a default value for the method parameter.

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/books/locale/{lcid:int?}")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksByLocale(int lcid = 1033) { ... }
}
```

Reference: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional

Or a better approach (if that works in your scenario) would be to have 2 different routes:

```
[Route("api/books/{id}")]
public BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id){...}
}
[Route("api/books")]
public BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(){...}
}
```